# How to use Restsharp with a plain text body

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am trying to fulfil this Ebay access token WebRequest

The server expects

> **HTTP method**: POST
> **URL**: https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token
>
> HTTP headers :
>
> **Content-Type** = application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> **Authorization** = Basic
>
> Request body (wrapped for readability):
>
> ```
> grant_type=client_credentials&
> redirect_uri=<RuName-value>&
> scope=https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_sc
> ```

This is working using a `WebRequest` as shown

```
var credentials = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clientId + ":" + clientSecret));

var request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token") as HttpWebRequest;

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, credentials);
            
var formData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("grant_type=client_credentials&redirect_uri=" + ruName + "&scope=https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope");
request.ContentLength = formData.Length;


using (var post = request.GetRequestStream())
{
   post.Write(formData, 0, formData.Length);
}

using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
   string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

However the following `RestSharp` request is returning an error

> Invalid Request

```
var resource = "identity/v1/oauth2/token";
var request = new RestRequest(resource, Method.POST);
var credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clientId + ":" + clientSecret));
request.AddParameter("Authorization", $"Basic {credentials}", ParameterType.HttpHeader);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var body = $"grant_type=client_credentials&redirect_uri={ruName}&scope=https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope";
request.AddParameter("text/xml", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
var client = new RestClient("https://api.sandbox.ebay.com");

return client.Execute<T>(request);
```

Comment: Why `text/xml`?

Comment: Yeah i dont quiet understand the http plumbing going on, i guess it needs to be application/x-www-form-urlencoded, i assumed it was just plain text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following worked for me, but I'm open to better answers:

```
var resource = "identity/v1/oauth2/token";
var request = new RestRequest(resource, Method.POST);
var credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clientId + ":" + clientSecret));
request.AddParameter("Authorization", $"Basic {credentials}", ParameterType.HttpHeader);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var body = $"grant_type=client_credentials&redirect_uri={ruName}&scope=https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope";
var formData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", formData, ParameterType.RequestBody);
var client = new RestClient("https://api.sandbox.ebay.com");

return GetResult<T>(client, request);
```

Note the lines

```
var body = $"grant_type=client_credentials&redirect_uri={ruName}&scope=https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope";
var formData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", formData, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```